# Check if A role has perms - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here Is a Good question. I want to check all roles in a server for admin, then create a new channel and allow only those set roles to have access. I dont want to use `@commands.has_guild_permissions()`.

Comment: You should create a list of all roles with admin when your bot gets added, then whenever a role gets made update the list. then all you have to do is create the channel when the bot is added, then update accordingly to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by roles with admin you mean any role that has the `Administrator` permission on (not just the server's owner), then every time you create a new channel, they will have access to it. Meaning you don't need to check for the roles if your only goal is to create the channel that only they can use. You would just have to set the default permissions to `False`, making the channel only accessible to people with Admin roles and Bots:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def admins_channel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='cool-channel')
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
```